# Type mismatch with CDate

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word, type-mismatch

I have the following code:

```
minDate = CDate(Table.Cell(i, 4).Range.Text)
```

But I get a "Type mismatch error".
`Table.Cell(i, 4)` is in a "dd.mm.yy" format.

Comment: What is `Table`? Can you show how it's defined?

Comment: Set Table = oDoc.Tables(1)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I wrote a macro to test this and the date format `dd.mm.yyyy` is invalid, it seems you must use `dd/mm/yyyy` (using slashes instead of period) or `dd-mm-yyyy` (using hyphens instead of periods):

```
Sub Macro1()

    Dim minDate As Date
    Dim DateStr As String

    ' with slashes, ok
    DateStr = "27/12/2013"
    minDate = CDate(DateStr)

    ' replace periods w/ slashes, ok
    DateStr = "27.12.2013"
    minDate = CDate(Replace(DateStr, ".", "/"))

    ' replace periods w/ hyphens, ok
    DateStr = "27.12.2013"
    minDate = CDate(Replace(DateStr, ".", "-"))

    ' type mismatch
    DateStr = "27.12.2013"
    minDate = CDate(DateStr)

End Sub
```

So, to solve your problem, you just need to replace all periods in your date to either hyphen or slash:

```
minDate = CDate(Replace(Table.Cell(i, 4).Range.Text, ".", "/"))
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
minDate = CDate(Table.Cell(i, 4))
```

Comment: Still raises "type mismatch"

Comment: @DarkSun Then the problem is either with `Table`, `i`, or `minDate`.  `Table` must be a Range and `minDate` should be either a Variant or a Date and `i` should hold any integer type number.

Comment: Is it needed only for CDate? Bacause msgBox (Table.Cell(i, 4).Range.Text) works great

Comment: Embarrassingly, I totally read that as Excel code and not Word code, so please disregard my answer... I suspect David R is correct :)

Answer (score 0):

The date conversion performance depends on the date format settings in Region and Language.
The following function ensures a successful conversion:

```
Function TextToDate(vstrText) As Variant
' Description: Convert Text Date to Date
'--
    Dim d As Variant
    Dim sDate As String
    sDate = Replace(vstrText, ".", "-")
    If Right(sDate, 1) = "-" Then
        sDate = Left(sDate, Len(sDate) - 1)
    End If
    If IsDate(sDate) Then
        d = CDate(sDate)
    Else
        d = ""
    End If
    TextToDate = d
End Function
```